# Play Console: stuck on "Ready to Publish"

Tags: google-play-console

I uploaded my android appbundle to Play Console in internal testing and then promoted it to production. Now I have this:

[image]

I have tried my best to proceed further but I couldn't find any button like "Review the release" or "Publish now" etc. It's my first time I tried to promote it from an internal test to production.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I accidentally turned `Managed publishing on` and I found my retained release in `Publishing overview` on the left drawer in Play Console and published it from there.

[image]

if you want to turn it off, just click on `Manage` and then `Managed Publishing Off`.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The initial release I could push from the release page after the review was completed.
Then I created a release in the closed testing and it gets stuck.  I got it unstuck following this advice.
Is it a sequence issue? Perhaps it is better to create the release and have it reviwied before adding to a track?

Comment: No, it's not an issue but it's a good feature from Playconsole, we are here because we were unaware of this feature.

Comment: Yes. It is perfect

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

#### 1. Go to Dashboard and click on 'Go to publishing overview'

[image]

#### 2. After that click on 'Send for Review'

[image]

Comment: For some reason, I don't see that blue button "Send for review" on the right side of "Changes ready to send for review". I'm wondering if this could be due to a change in my account permissions...

Comment: Mine same, i uploaded the bundle, start full rollout, then in Publishing, i clicked Send for Review, but, on the dashboard it still says Ready to send for review.!!!!

Comment: Did you get an answer, guys? I don't see the button as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the "Send for Review" button in the "Publishing overview" screen. I am an Admin in the account.

When I copied the URL and opened it in a new browser tab, the magical blue button appeared.